# How can I create a decimal-only BasicEditField in BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I'm completely new to BlackBerry development, but I'm experienced in Java ME development. While creating my first to-be-published app, I came across a `BasicEditField` that *has* to be constricted to decimal-only (this app is a currency conversion app).

But so far I have not seen a way to do this. I can use `BasicEditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC` and it will allow only numbers to be typed, but no decimals. The [BlackBerry Java Quick Start Guide](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/index.jsp?name=UI%20Component%20-%20Quick%20Reference%20Guide%20-%20BlackBerry%20Java%20SDK6.0&language=English&userType=21&category=Development%20Guides&subCategory=) also doesn't have an example like that.

As this is a fairly common situation, I think there should be some way to achieve this. Any ideas anyone?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a programming problem, but a user-level problem.

`BasicEditField.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC` works just fine, and it allows input of positive and negative values with or without decimals. You only have to type the dot key to insert a decimal separator.

Comment: Could you post the code where you are instantiating the field? I'm a long time BB programmer and have used decimals in editfields without any problem.

Comment: Sorry, it was my wrong.. I have used `BasicEditField.FILTER_NUMERIC` and not `.FILTER_REAL_NUMERIC`. Now it works, but got a new problem: Why does it allows multiple decimal-points?

Comment: Because RIMs libraries are full of bugs and inconsistent behavior. To prevent that, you could extend `NumericTextFilter`, override the `validate` methods to get the count of how many dots there are, and then set to your field with `setTextFilter`.